# My page isn't extending the way I want to / some margin issue

Tags: html, css

I used the following code on every website I made:

```
*{
  margin:0; 
  padding0;
}
```

Today I learned that this is not good practise. I've been trying to create a website without it but I run into some issues i'm not sure how to fix.
I have margins that I cant seem to remove. **note that if I use the following code it fixes it. But I dont want to have 0 margin/padding on every item.

```
html, body {
  margin 0;
}
```

Not sure were to add the margin:0; then.

Also as u can see in the preview the page isn't exteding for some reason. I did some research, but these tutorials didn't help.

So in a nutshell: I have white spaces that I dont know to remove(to the left and top), the page isn't extending corretly(The sidebar needs to be as long as the site is, same for the timeline)

http://codepen.io/Aphryv/pen/xwLZXv?editors=110

The design I created:
[image]

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? Which whitespace are you talking about? Which page isn't extending?

Comment: where did you learned it isnt good practice ? I don't see it problem to do *{}

Comment: @SzymonDziewoński https://css-tricks.com/margin-0-padding-0-no-longer-cool/

Comment: Use the Dev Tools of your browser to identify the CSS rule that applies to the elements with wrong margins.

Comment: @SzymonDziewoński basically it's can destroy some useful styling, but much worse is that it can severely impact load times since it has to apply to all elements on the page.

Comment: well are youing big webpage ? like for example allegor or whatever big page? if now it is still good practice

Comment: @Supersharp I did, and I saw nothing. I think its the basic styling from the web browser

Comment: @patricksweeney its make all browsers consistent about rendering , unless you wont use it for really big website it is not bad.

Comment: then apply a CSS rule with a margin of 0 to the element you want.

Comment: @Supersharp When I do this on <section class="sidebar"> this isn't working.

Comment: then apply the *no-margin* rule to the parent element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats pretty understandable, even i do have undergone through this problem while i was learning the basics of HTML and CSS, so the solution is if you use "**position**" property before using any other property in your particular "div" that would result in removing the white spaces, because position property is used to align the element accordingly and hence removing the white spaces and Now we have majorly 4 type of position property so you can go through that as per your requirement.
Hope this would help you out